# mail: Cannot parse address

Tags: email, backup, sendmail, syntax, s3cmd

This is the command I use to tar my backup files, write to stdout and then upload everything to Amazon S3 with an email notification.

```
tar -czvf - --exclude-caches /var/www | s3cmd --reduced-redundancy --multipart-chunk-size-mb=30 put - s3://MY-BUCKET/`date +\%G-\%m-\%d`.tar.gz | mail -s "Weekly Backup"
```

Everything works fine except the `mail` command. I think I have some syntax error.. as I get:

```
mail: Cannot parse address `File '-' stored as 's3://MY-BUCKET/2014-08-31.tar.gz' (0 bytes in 2190.3 seconds' (while expanding `File '-' stored as 's3://MY-BUCKET/2014-08-31.tar.gz' (0 bytes in 2190.3 seconds'): Malformed email address
mail: Cannot parse address `-1.00 B/s) [1 of 1]' (while expanding `-1.00 B/s) [1 of 1]'): Malformed email address
root:~# tar -czvf - --exclude-caches /var/www | s3cmd --reduced-redundancy --multipart-chunk-size-mb=30 put - s3://MY-BUCKET/`date +\%G-\%m-\%d`.tar.gz
 | mail -s "Weekly Backup"
```

Comment: You forgot to actually specify an email address!

Comment: Since the command is run on crontab I thought the MAILTO at the top of the file was enough. No?

Comment: MAILTO in crontab specifies where to send "unchatched" output to stdout and stderr.  It does not apped missing command line options to `mail` command.

Answer (score 3):

To send a mail via `mail` (and using stdin as body), use the following syntax:

```
echo "test body" | mail -s 'test subject' reciever@example.com
```

For more information take a look at the Manpage `man mail`.